# Relationship between number of trials and complementary CDF of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a question related to Binomial distribution. Can someone help me?

Consider the following complementary CDF of a binomial distribution with parameters n and p :

$$
\bar{F}(x) = \sum_{k=x+1}^{n}(^n _k)p^k(1-p)^{n-k} 
$$

Is the complementary CDF non-decreasing in n? If yes, how does one prove it?

My intuition is that the complementary CDF is non-decreasing in n. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the complementary CDF non-decreasing in n

$n$ is a given number in a Binomial law. $k$ is the variable.

It is non- increasing.

A property of any CDF is that it is non-decreasing, and it is evident as, by definition, the CDF is the cumulative probability function.
Its complement, 1-CDF, is obviously non-increasing in $k$.

Comment: I am interested in the case where x and p are fixed and n is varying. Consider the example where x =10, p=0.85, and n varies from 100 to 120. For this example, I want to prove mathematically that complementary CDF is non-decreasing as n varies from 100 to 120.

Comment: @Sreekz : in the situation you explained then the rv is not a binomial. It is a Negative Binomial, its pmf is different with respect the one you showed but the proof is the same. Any CDF is non -decreasing by definition (being a Cumulated probability function) and thus its complement is non increasing